# Split nested array into multiple arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like this:

```
str = {1|2|3|4|5}{a|b|c|d|e}
```

I want to split it into multiple arrays. One containing all the first elements in each {}, one containing the second element, etc. Like this:

```
arr_0 = [1,a]
arr_1 = [2,b]
arr_2 = [3,c]
```

.....

The best I can come up with is:

```
var str_array = str.split(/}{/);

for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++){
    var str_row = str_array[i];
    var str_row_array = str_row.split('|');
    arr_0.push(str_row_array[0]);
    arr_1.push(str_row_array[1]);
    arr_2.push(str_row_array[2]);
    arr_3.push(str_row_array[3]);
    arr_4.push(str_row_array[4]);
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: `str_row_array` is an array, you can iterate over it, exactly the same way you iterate over `str_array`. `arr_0` --- is a silly idea from the beginning, use arrays instead `arr[0]`

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
var zip = function(xs, ys) {
  var out = []
  for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
    out[i] = [xs[i], ys[i]]
  }
  return out
}

var res = str
  .split(/\{|\}/) // ['', '1|2|3|4|5', '', 'a|b|c|d|e', '']
  .filter(Boolean) // ['1|2|3|4|5', 'a|b|c|d|e']
  .map(function(x){return x.split('|')}) // [['1','2','3','4','5'], ['a','b','c','d','e']]
  .reduce(zip)
/*^
[['1','a'],
 ['2','b'],
 ['3','c'],
 ['4','d'],
 ['5','e']]
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

```
var str = '{1|2|3|4|5}{a|b|c|d|e}'.match(/[^{}]+/g).map(function(a) {
       return a.match(/[^|]+/g);
    }),
    i,
    result = {};

for (i = 0; i < str[0].length; i += 1) {
  result["arr_" + i] = [+str[0][i], str[1][i]];
}
```

### How it works

The first part, takes the string, and splits it into the two halves. The map will return an array after splitting them after the `|`. So `str` is left equal to:

```
[
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
]
```

The for loop will iterate over the `[1,2,3,4,5]` array and make the array with the appropriate values. The array's are stored in a object. The object we are using is called `result`. If you don't wish for it to be kept in `result`, read `Other`

#### Other

Because you can't make variable names from another variable, feel free to change `result` to `window` or maybe even `this` *(I don't know if that'll work)* You can also make this an array

### Alternate

```
var str = '{1|2|3|4|5}{a|b|c|d|e}'.match(/[^{}]+/g).map(function(a) { return a.match(/[^|]+/g); }),
    result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < str[0].length; i += 1) {
  result[i] = [+str[0][i], str[1][i]];
}
```

This is very similar except will generate an `Array` containing arrays like the other answers,